# Getting link id on click from one html page and send it to another one

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, hyperlink

I have an index.html page with products and for each of them I set the name and set the id of the link using a database query (with php).

```
echo '<li id='.$row["id"].'><a href="#">'.$row["name"].'</a></li>';
```

Everything is fine so far. So I have a link with the unique id from the database for this product. My question is when I click on this link and it redirects me to the productPage.html, how can I send the ID of the link so I can use it to get the information from the database and display if to the products page?

Comment: Attach the id to the end of the url in the query string.

Answer (score 2):

First thing is the change your *productPage.html* to *productPage.php* so it can parse PHP.

Change your link to:

```
echo '<li id='.$row["id"].'><a href="productPage.php?id='.$row["id"].'" >'.$row["name"].'</a></li>';
```

Then on your *productPage.php* you will read the id from QueryString like this:

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

here's how you pass variables between pages

```
echo '<li id='.$row["id"].'><a href="link_to_page.php?id=.$row["id"]. ">'.$row["name"].'</a></li>';
```